# Can not add value in List property bag using CSOM

Tags: client-object-model, office-365, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

I have saved value in list property bag from provider hosted using CSOM code:

```
list.Context.Load(list.RootFolder);
list.Context.ExecuteQuery();
var properties = list.RootFolder.Properties.FieldValues;
properties["Key"] = Value;
list.RootFolder.Update();
list.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

The settings are saved successfully but at the time of retrieving the values from list property bag it shows the key not exist. 
Code to get key from property bag:

```
list.Context.Load(list.RootFolder);
list.Context.ExecuteQuery();
string settings = list.RootFolder.Properties.FieldValues.ContainsKey("key")
            ? Convert.ToString(list.RootFolder.Properties["key"])
            : String.Empty;
```

Kindly suggest where am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How to set property in List**

[PropertyValue.FieldValues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.propertyvalues.fieldvalues.aspx) is **read-only** property, the following example demonstrates how to set property for a List:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var listProperties = list.RootFolder.Properties;
listProperties[key] = value;
list.RootFolder.Update();
list.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

**How to load properties for a List**

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
ctx.Load(list, l => l.RootFolder.Properties);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var pValue = list.RootFolder.Properties[key]; //get property value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vadim Gremyachev. Can you also suggest how to remove a property from list property bag as there is no method to remove a value from list properties using CSOM ?

Comment: You could try something like this: listProperties[key] = null;